# Integrating OpenCV with XCode - Excluded Architecture

Tags: xcode, opencv, xcode13

### Tried to use OpenCV library in swift.

The library forces me to implement changes below :
[image: Excluded Architectures]

### Otherwise, without those changes i get an error:

[image: OpenCV Error]
Also in this App i want the user to pick an image from phone's gallery. To handle it, I'm using PHPicker.
**However, with Excluded Architectures set, I'm not able to pick any image from the gallery**, there's buch of errors/warnings in Terminal.
Without Excluded Architectures app will crash with Error as at second screen.
Any ideas or tips ?

## Error from screen

```
Ld /Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.app/OpenCVTest normal (in target 'OpenCVTest' from project 'OpenCVTest')
    cd /Users/Kacper/Downloads/OpenCVTest
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target arm64-apple-ios12.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -L/Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Kacper/Downloads/OpenCVTest -filelist /Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/OpenCVTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/OpenCVTest.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/OpenCVTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/OpenCVTest_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -stdlib\=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/OpenCVTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/OpenCVTest.swiftmodule -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/OpenCVTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.build/OpenCVTest.app-Simulated.xcent -framework opencv2 -framework CoreFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework CoreGraphics -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreMedia -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/OpenCVTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/OpenCVTest_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Kacper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OpenCVTest-agzhkmtplgmvfohcejwaizkysxoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenCVTest.app/OpenCVTest

ld: in /Users/Kacper/Downloads/OpenCVTest/opencv2.framework/opencv2(ios_conversions.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

*Text formating of error is not my fault!*

Comment: no pictures of text. edit your question and put the text there instead of the screenshot.

Comment: W/e, i'm going to paste text tomorrow. For me screen was more clear and cleaner than tons of text in question.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz there's the error.

Comment: so, `building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64` I guess that means you need the library built *for the simulator*, not for the actual target device.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly fine with plugged iPhone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so, building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64 I guess that means you need the library built for the simulator, not for the actual target device.

It works when you try compile it, using real iPhone/iPad

Comment: how to Build opencv2 in xcode simulators?